# How to reduce copy-pasting?

Tags: java

If I have a number of similar classes, say:

```
Integer i0;
Integer i1;
Integer i2;
Integer i3;
Integer i4;
Integer i5;
Integer i6;
Integer i7;
Integer i8;
Integer i9;
```

And wanted to avoid doing this:

```
i0 = 0;
i1 = 1;
i2 = 2;
i3 = 3;
i4 = 4;
i5 = 5;
i6 = 6;
i7 = 7;
i8 = 8;
i9 = 9;
```

I'm thinking of doing something similar to this to achieve the same result:

```
int cnt = 0;
for(classname : arrayOfClassNames {
    classname = cnt++;
}
```

How do I do that?

[**clarification**] I appears I was misunderstood. I was thinking more along the lines of having 10 separate classes still, not one array having 10 items.

Answer (score 9):

Use an array or an ArrayList?

```
// using an array
Integer[] ints = new Integer[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ints[i] = i;
}

// using an array list
ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ints.add(i);
}
```

Following on from your update, what you are looking to do can be achieved using

```
Class.forName(classname).newInstance();
```

However, I would suggest that whatever you save in time to code it, you will lose in readability and ease of maintenance, so you may find this a false economy.

Answer (score 5):

Store them in an array:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[10];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    array[i] = i ;
}
```

To get i9: `array[9]`

Answer (score 1):

A number of similar classes sounds like you want an Array:

```
Integer[] manyI = new Integer[] {0, 1, 2, ....};
```

Or you fill the Array with a loop:

```
Integer[] manyI = new Integer[10];
for (int i = 0; i < manyI.length; i++) manyI[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `java.util.Map<T, K>`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  map.put("i" + i, i);
}

System.out.println(map);
System.out.println("i8: " + map.get("i8"));
```